# Is $ d(U,V) = 0 $? True/false

Tags: general-topology

> Given   $(X, d)$ be a metric space and let $U$ and $V$ be non-empty subsets of $X$. Define
>   $d(U,V) = \inf\{d(u,v) : u \in U, v\in V\}$.

Is the following statement is true/false

> If $U$ and $V$ are compact and disjoint, then $d(U,V) > 0$

My attempt : I thinks  this statment is false

I take  $U= [-1,0]$ and $V= [1,2]$ both $U$ and $V$ are compact and disjoint .

Now for   each $\epsilon >0$ , we have  $\frac{-\epsilon}{2} \in [-1,0] $and $\frac{\epsilon}{2} \in [1,2]$ so that   $d([-1,0], [1,2] \le d(-\frac{\epsilon}{2}, \frac{\epsilon}{2}) = \epsilon $  since $d([-1,0], [1,2])\le \epsilon $ for  every $\epsilon >0$. Now  we conclude that  it is $0$ so its  contradicts that  $d(U,V) >0$

Is its  true ?

Comment: Are you sure that $\frac{\epsilon}{2} \in [1,2]$?

Comment: In your example, $d([-1,0],[1,2]) = 1 > 0$.  In general, the statement is true (because your sets are compact, you may replace the infimum with a minimum, from which an argument follows).

Comment: @XanderHenderson$ d([-1,0],[1,2]) = [0,2] $  infimum is 0

Comment: @jasmine The distance $d(U,V)$ is a **number**, not an interval.  Assuming that $d(x,y) = |x-y|$, then you are incorrect.  $d([-1,0],[1,2])$ is **not** zero.  In fact, if $x \in [-1,0]$ and $y \in [1,2]$, then $x \le 0$ and $y \ge 1$.  This implies that $$ x \le 0 < 1 \le y. $$  Therefore $d([-1,0],[1,2]) \ge 1$.  To get equality, take $x=0$ and $y=1$.

Comment: thank u  got  it now @XanderHenderson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$d$ is a continuous function from $X^2$ to $\Bbb R$. So the image of a compact set is compact, that is, a closed and bounded set, that is contained in a closed and bounded interval.

Answer (score 1):

Let $d(U,V)=\inf\{d(u,v):u\in U,v\in V\}=0.$ Then $\exists$ sequences $\{u_n\}\subset U,\{v_n\}\subset V$ such that $0\le d(u_n,v_n)<\dfrac{1}{n}~\forall~n.$ Since $U$ is compact, $\exists$ a convergent subsequene $\{u_{r_n}\}$ of $\{u_n\}$ converging to some $u\in U.$ Then $0\le d(u_{r_n},v_{r_n})<\dfrac{1}{r_n}~\forall~n.$ Similarly since $V$ is compact, $\exists$ a convergent subsequene $\{v_{r_{n_m}}\}$ of $\{v_{r_n}\}$ converging to some $v\in V.$ Then $0\le d(u_{r_{n_m}},b_{r_{n_m}})$$<\dfrac{1}{r_{n_m}}~\forall~m.$ We note that $r_{n_m}\ge n_m\ge m>0$$\implies0<\dfrac{1}{r_{n_m}}<\dfrac{1}{m}\to0$$\implies\dfrac{1}{r_{n_m}}\to0.$ Using the sqeezing lemma once again we can see that $\exists$ convergent sequences $\{u_n\}\subset U$ and $\{v_n\}\subset V$ such that $u_n\to u\in U,v_n\to v\in V.$ $\exists$ convergent sequences $\{u_n\}\subset U$ and $\{v_n\}\subset V$ such that $u_n\to u\in U,v_n\to v\in V.$ Then $d(u_n,v_n)\to d(u,v)$ Consequently, $d(u,v)=0\implies u=v,$ a contradiction to $U\cap V=\emptyset.$

Answer (score 0):

For any closed set $U$ and compact set $V$, $U \cap V = \emptyset$ implies $d(U,V) > 0$ and similarly, $d(U,V) > 0$ implies that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint.